# Visual Studio 2017 wants a reference for something that is already referenced using a different assembly

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I am having a hard time tracking down the reason for this error in Visual Studio 2017. The error is here:

[image]

I am clearly using the System.Drawing assembly for the Brush, but it still seems to want the System.Drawing.Common assembly. Here is the simple property it is referencing (I added the System.Drawing locally instead of a 'using' just to make absolute sure it is referencing the correct assembly):

```
private System.Drawing.Brush brush_ = System.Drawing.Brushes.Black;

public System.Drawing.Brush PBrush
    {
        get { return brush_; }
        set { brush_ = value; }
    }
```

Any feedback on why this is happening would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: What type of project and which version are you using?

Comment: @RuiJarimba I am using a .Net Core project targeting the 4.6.1 framework. I was under the impression you could still use .net standard libraries under the Core framework.

Comment: Have you tried turning it off and back on again? Seriously, I have had this issue resolved the easy way after trouble shooting a few too many times.

Comment: @AustinTFrench I have tried restarting several times, cleaning the solution several times, even deleting the class and starting from scratch a few times.This is driving me crazy.

Comment: Are you sure that PBrush is property of the Brush Class?

Comment: @T James: 1)  Austin T French is absolutely correct.  I've seen it a zillion times, under a zillion different circumstances, against all versions of MSVS.  "Delete config/re-add config" works almost as often as `<Ctl-Alt-Del>` works ;)  2) "using" in a .cs source file != "referencing assembly" in a project.  Are you sure you have an explicit reference to the .Net `System.Drawing.Common` assembly in your project?

Comment: @paulsm4 Perhaps a stupid question, but why do I need an explicit reference to System.Drawing.Common if I am trying to use System.Drawing? Thanks!

Comment: _why do I need an explicit reference to System.Drawing.Common if I am trying to use System.Drawing?_  `System.Drawing` is both a **namespace** and an **assembly**.  `System.Drawing.Common` is an **assembly**.  Both of the assemblies `System.Drawing` and `System.Drawing.Common` define a namespace called `System.Drawing`.  The Object Browser (View menu or Ctrl+Alt+J) should let you determine what namespace Brush is in **and** what assembly that namespace is in.  Search for Brush then click on the "is in" namespace (lower right) and then click on the "is in" assembly name (lower right again).

Comment: You cannot use an assembly that was built to target .NETCore in a project that targets .NET 4.x.  You must rebuild it, targeting .NETStandard2.0.  It might still prompt you to add that assembly btw, necessary to forward the types in the .netstandard library to the framework types.  Update the target to 4.7.x or just keep it happy.

Comment: @FrankBoyne Understood, thanks for the clarification. My confusion stems from the fact that I have never before needed a reference to the assembly System.Drawing.Common to use the Brush. It is apparent I need to read a lot more about the way the .NET Core architecture works.

Comment: "More reading..." could never hurt.  But just stop assuming s--t, try stuff out, and empirically learn "what works" ... *regardless* of whether or not it seems to "make sense". Remember the aphorism: "When you 'assume', it makes an Ass of U and ME" ;)